# How can I use Delphi VCL Sensors (GPS)

Tags: windows, delphi, gps, sensors, vcl

I have a Microsoft Surface Go 2 with GPS (no SIM card).  The GPS works fine, in Google maps and in 2 apps downloaded from the Microsoft Store.  I am developing on a desktop, and moving the EXE and APPX files to the Surface.

I want to access the GPS from a VCL program, using the current 10.4.1.  The sample VCLSensors program compiles, but only the Accelleromater produces results.  The Orienation gives all NAN, and the Location is blank.  I cannot find any permissions that need to be set.

I tried creating and installing an APPX file, using the directions at https://blogs.embarcadero.com/deploying-windows-10-apps-through-the-microsoft-store-1863306656/, to include setting up an Ad Hoc certificate.  This fails with a Windows message about an untrusted certificate.

I also tried the FMX demo SensorInfo, which also shows only the Accelorometer.

Any suggestions on how to get the VCL unit sensors to work with GPS?